# WCF service in windows phone

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I don't know to decide, what should I use in windows phone app. WCF service library or WCF service application? I've tried to create the first one, but I can't add reference to it. So i've tried add service reference, but no service found. 
Second one WCF service app is working, add service reference find my service and i can work with it, but it's hosted on development server.
Please, give me good advice, should I use first choice or second choice?
I have to note, that these service will be used my phone app and web app too. thanks

**EDIT:**
Finally I gonna use WCF service application. When I click discover and go, I get this error:

```
The type 'WcfNotificationService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

Comment: On Windows phone you should probably use neither, you should use a client technology. Or are you talking about your backend system? Can you provide more detail in your question?

Comment: My WP app should send emails from backgroundagent. I can send email via wcf, without user interaction(EmailTaskLauncher - not exactly). Next, app should send data to the DB on server. The user can work with data with my custom web app(asp.net webform).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host a WCF Service in IIS, you should use "WCF Service Application". The library is just a service library, without any hosting.

Comment: Ok, I use wcf service app. Let me ask you something. I created wcf library. Then I added service reference after some experiments. Everything's gone. BUT! When i created new instance of service "var client = new ServiceClient()" it gave me exception KeyNotFound. The file ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is set to copy always, but he is empty! Why?

Comment: If it actually was a *library* then you have no hosting information like binding and URL inside and the "Add Service Reference..." could not save them in the client config file.

Comment: So I could set up this informations with WCF service config. editor?

Comment: First, you must *host* your service somewhere. Maybe your local development IIS. Then create a service reference using this URL.

Comment: Apologize me for my stupid questions. Can I host service for example in ConsoleApplication and then use it in Windows Phone as service reference?

Comment: You will need to read a tutorial, theres a lot of them all over the net. Explaining how to create and host a WCF service is out of the scope of this site.